# PostgreSQL: Using subquery abbreviation ('AS') in the WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, sql

Consider the following query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT 
    a, b, 
   (A VERY LONG AND COMPLICATED SUBQUERY) AS c,
   (ANOTHER VERY LONG AND COMPLICATED SUBQUERY) AS d
FROM table
```

I want to have `c` and `d` in the `WHERE` clause, like:

```
WHERE c AND d;
```

But, as far as I know, I can only do:

```
WHERE A VERY LONG AND COMPLICATED SUBQUERY) AND 
   (ANOTHER VERY LONG AND COMPLICATED SUBQUERY)
```

Which is clumsy, code-replicating, [breaking the single-choice principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_choice_principle) and utterly ugly.

By the way, the same problem applies to the `SELECT` clause: I can not use abbreviations for previously-defined subqueries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d FROM
    (SELECT 
        a, b, 
        (A VERY LONG AND COMPLICATED SUBQUERY) AS c,
        (ANOTHER VERY LONG AND COMPLICATED SUBQUERY) AS d
        FROM table
    ) AS T1
WHERE c AND d
```

You could also do this with a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).

Comment: Working. Any idea why the more reasonable syntax isn't working in the PostgreSQL environment?

Comment: Evaluation of the WHERE clause logically precedes evaluation of the
SELECT list, so it's really quite nonsensical to expect SELECT outputs
to be available in WHERE.

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2002-11/msg01411.php

Comment: @Adam: I added another alternative (CTEs) to my answer. Also you should check out the HAVING clause (it's also mentioned in Gerard's link).

Comment: @Gerard: I think it can be replaced by some preprocessing search-and-replace mechanism. @Mark thanks - looking into it.

Comment: @MarkByers Thank you for adding the CTE link, the WITH clause was exactly what I was looking for to solve my issue.